# I am creating a compound interest program on Python, and it says "TypeError: a float is required". I don't know what I have done incorrectly

Tags: python-2.7

Here is the part on the program that is Python says needs a "float":

```
if selection == 5:
    p5=input("Please enter the principle amount.")
    r5=input("Please enter the rate as a decimal.")
    t5=input("Please enter the number of years you wish to keep the money stored.")
    A=p5*math.e,(r5*t5)
    Ar=round(A,2)
    print "The amount after",t5,"years is",Ar,"."
```

Comment: `A` is a tuple containing two values, `p5 * math.e` and `r5 * t5`; I doubt that's what you wanted. What's the comma for?!

Comment: "(r5*t5)"is supposed to be the exponent of "p5*math.e". How do I show that? The formula I'm using is "A=P*e^r5*t5" (compounding continually) @jonrsharpe

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#numbers

Answer (score 1):

`**` is the exponent operator in Python, not `,`

`A = p5*math.e**(r5*t5)` would give the unrounded amount you are looking for.

The error that you are getting is due to the unintentionally created [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) `(p5*math.e, r5*t5)` being passed to `round`.

To illustrate the problem more directly, `round((2.0, 3.0), 2)` would give the same "TypeError: a float is required" because `(2.0, 3.0)` is a tuple.